# Android: UI design question

Tags: android, user-interface

Im wondering about how to layout an activity in an application. It deals with the concept of a 'home' from study. On this page there is address information, phone numbers, etc.

I want to give the user a means to go to other pages that have related information about the home and Im wondering what method to use (IE a link, a button, a menu). EG Who lives in the home? Currently this info is in a list on the page. Clicking a name will send the user to a new activity dealing with that person. Is this an appropriate design? The same issues will be there for the 'subject' pages too.

I also want to provide a means to open a navigation window or deal with Inventory for that home. These are displayed as buttons on the page but it just doesn't seem right.

I guess Im looking for design guidelines. The code part is essentially done. When does one use a menu vs a button (or a link/clickable field) on a mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently found a great website devoted entirely to design patterns [here](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/).
One of the main features that the person running this website heavily advises is to use an [actionbar](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/01/implementing-dashboard-and-action-bar.html).
The website has a lot of good examples and code to help.
If there are a lot of associated actions, you can implement it the way the evernote app is organized (see [this](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2010/12/action-bar-update-1.html) post).
You can also implement the action menu design pattern.

For a full list of design patterns, follow [this](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/p/android-ui-pattern-collection.html) link.

Comment: Hard to find stuff on the site. Good idea though. Got a specific pattern for this question?

Comment: Yes - the action bar. If you read the site, you'll see that there is a pattern for dealing with pages that have multiple actions associated with them. See my post above for links.

Comment: I don't feel the action bar is a good location for navigation buttons. But that may be a personal preference. Like I said, good website. Thanks for the share

Comment: Do you think its necc to have a means to go to your app's 'start' page available on every page or is the 'back' button sufficient?

Comment: Hmm.. looks like using the "actionbar" gives you this icon automatically.

Comment: I think from what I read on that site, the means to go to the 'start' page is built-in as you say. If you don't like that, you can make your own and put at the top of every layout. Casp.

Answer (score 2):

The design standard, at least for my company, is to put settings, options, and configuration items in the options menu. Or advanced actions that most users won't be using. All other actions such as navigation are put on the screen as links, images, buttons, etc...

You're design sounds good from a UI guideline stand point. Screen shots may help those answering these questions give you more detailed answers on specific items.

Just a quick note, tabs are another good design for navigation different views of an "object" rather than buttons.